# Control Properties of LinkLabel when used for HelpProvider

Tags: vb.net, chm

I am working with Visual Studio 2017, working in VB.  I am linking to a .CHM file from a `LinkLabel` which works fine with following code:

```
Private Sub LinkLabel2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkLabel2.Click
    ' Create link to help file
    System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(Me, "RPM_Help.chm", HelpNavigator.AssociateIndex)
End Sub
```

I use a simple image to indicate the link to the .chm file that is 32x32 pixels in size, I have been playing with the properties of `LinkLabel2` but I just can't figure out how to make the entire label a link space. I did find that unless there is a Text property on the label a MouseOver cursor will not show up, but how can I make the entire label image a cursor link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the code and image below this can be solved by using `LinkLabel2.AutoSize = False` and adding a ToolTip from Common Controls to the form in design mode.

Each control, such as Buttons and TextBoxes, will acquire a `ToolTip on toolTip1` property when you add a `toolTip1` to your designer view. You can access this property in the Properties pane to set the tool tips.

```
Public Class frmMain

  Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LinkLabel2.BackColor = Color.CornflowerBlue
    LinkLabel2.AutoSize = False
    LinkLabel2.Width = 168
    LinkLabel2.Height = 40
    LinkLabel2.Text = ""
  End Sub

  Private Sub LinkLabel1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.Click
    ' --- Open help file - Table of contents
    System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(Me, "hlp/CHM-example.chm", HelpNavigator.TableOfContents)
  End Sub

  Private Sub LinkLabel2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkLabel2.Click
    ' --- Open help file - Index
    System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(Me, "hlp/CHM-example.chm", HelpNavigator.Index)
  End Sub

  Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    ' --- Open help file - Search
    System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(Me, "hlp/CHM-example.chm", HelpNavigator.Find, "")
  End Sub    

  Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
  End Sub

End Class
```

The code corresponds to the image shown. The values can of course also be set via the properties, but are included here in the FormLoad for documentation.

You may want to use a simple `PictureBox1_Click` event for your needs as shown below (third item in the "Show help" group box).

[image]